# I have no local IP on my CentOS 7.1 dedicated server

Tags: linux, centos, networking

**problem**

I've installed net tools and whenever I run `ifconfig -a` I come up with 2 network interfaces. Here is an example.

```
[root@81756 /]# ifconfig -a
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
        inet 69.30.199.146 netmask 255.255.255.248 broadcast 69.30.199.151
```

The rest is inet6 information and other information about how many bytes/packets have been sent/recieved.

The other network interface is just the `lo` loopback.

I'm trying to setup a PPTP VPN and this is really making it difficult.

---

**attempted**

I've tried manually putting a local IP into the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1` interface configuration, but that broke the server routing.

---

**additional**

The inet address in the `eno1` interface is also the server's public IP.

Comment: Your server has an IP address.  So what exactly is the question?

Comment: The local IP address is the public IP address. I don't seem to have any kind of local IP. That is the issue.

Comment: I was expecting to see an IP like you would on any typical local network I.E: 192.168.x.x; 172.16.x.x
Can I use the 127.0.x.x address in my PPTP settings?

Comment: So as for setting up the PPTP VPN, can I use the 127 address for my pptpd.conf settings? It needs my local and remote IP.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-your-own-vpn-with-pptp might help you with your PPTP. It's for a DigitalOcean VPS, but the principles will be the same for your dedicated server.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I'll try to get this working. If you'd post an answer I'd be happy to select it as correct.

Comment: It might be work renaming your question to refer to "private IP address" instead of local IP, so that others (inc search engines) will find this question.

Answer (score 0):

You will only see [private IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) like that when you're behind a [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) router. These are generally used at homes or small offices as they save the rather scarce IPv4 addresses from being used up and as a side-effect also help protect consumer devices from network based attacks.

Dedicated servers are directly on the Internet so that they can be accessed as servers and hence have a routable IP address, which is what you can currently see on the `eno1` interface. They are also susceptible to network attacks, so firewalls should be enabled and configured properly.

Your PPTP server will have a new IP address on the server. This should be from the private IP address range. The remote client will be another address in the same subnet. You'll also have to enable [IP forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_forwarding) and NAT on the server so that traffic can flow between this private network and the Internet.